# finding the busiest day within a date range by crosschecking multiple bookings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am working on a `room` `booking` app. Before making a new booking will search for room `availability` for the `check_in` and `check_out` dates by cross checking with `existing bookings` for the room

Each `room` has a field `available_quantity`. Lets say its `5` for this room. So I must ensure the `bookings` for the `room` wont `exceed` that on any day between the `check_in` and `check_out` period(in other words the total `rooms_needed` wont exceed `5(available_quantity)` in any given day)

My plan is first find all bookings that is within `check_in` and `check_out`

```
#find records with check_ins before the new checkout date && check_outs after the new checkin date
  scope :bookings_between, lambda {|start_date, end_date| where("check_in < ? AND check_out > ?", end_date, start_date )}
```

This works fine as I will get below output as `array` as expected

```
bookings=#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Booking id: 20, room_id: 29, buyer_id: 11, rooms_needed: 1,check_in: "2017-06-20", check_out: "2017-06-23">, #<Booking id: 21, room_id: 29, buyer_id: 11,rooms_needed: 1, check_in: "2017-06-20", check_out: "2017-06-23">, #<Booking id: 22, room_id: 29, buyer_id: 11,rooms_needed: 2, check_in: "2017-06-22", check_out: "2017-06-25">, #<Booking id: 23, room_id: 29, buyer_id: 11, rooms_needed: 1, check_in: "2017-06-22", check_out: "2017-06-25">]>
```

So basically these are the main values in the `array` now.

```
Range: 2017-06-20 .. 2017-06-23, rooms_needed: 1 
Range: 2017-06-20 .. 2017-06-23, rooms_needed: 1 
Range: 2017-06-22 .. 2017-06-25, rooms_needed: 2 
Range: 2017-06-22 .. 2017-06-25, rooms_needed: 1
```

Now what I want is find a day with `highest` `rooms_needed`(to make sure it wont exceed the `room_quantity`). The problem I find is that I need to consider `all the days within the range`. Could someone tell me how can I find that from this `bookings` array? Or am I over complicating this?? Thank you

> NB: Basically looking for how to `loop` through the `bookings` `array` and
>   `totalling` bookings for each day from the `check_in` day to `check_out`
>   day(as its a range how can I do this)

Comment: As per my understanding you want to find out such room which ll available for given date range(i.e between check in and check out). Am I right?

Comment: @GaneshSagare yes..but am not looking for any other rooms. Just one room. The property has many rooms of this same type.So what am looking for is how many rooms are sold out for any day within the check_in and check_out period. As it has many rooms my plan is to find the day with the highest room requirement within the check_in and check_out period and add it to present booking room requirement count. Looping to find the highest room requirement day by totaling bookings for a single day from the array is the issue I face and thats  the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand this right, what you need is the day with the highest `rooms_needed`:

```
array.order("rooms_needed DESC").first
```

And later you can check if that is lower that `room_quantity`.

Comment: highest rooms needed is the thing am looking for. But not for a single booking. The room will have multiple bookings on a single day. So I need to add room_requirement on each day and find a day with highest room requirement(actually not day but rooms_needed) Thats what am having difficultly in finding...

Comment: Please post your model, to see if I can help you.

Comment: `Room has_many Bookings`  `Booking belongs_to Room`   .Its actually simple as this. I finded all bookings that will be within the range already as mentioned in the question. But looping through each for every single day is where i got stuck as its a range instead of a proper date

Comment: I think you need to iterate over every single date between `check_in` and `check_out`, and in every iteration check the capacity.

Comment: yes thats what I want and the question is how to do that as its a range..